# Unable to check in files due to Error"You must fill out all required properties before checking in this document."

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, check-in

I receive this error "You must fill out all required properties before checking in this document." while trying to check in a file. I tried fill up all the properties for the file but still receiving this error. Anybody knows why?

[image: Error Message]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the list settings > Advanced settings > change it to No for "Allow management of content types" (don't worry it won't remove any content types).
2. Then set ALL the columns to non-required in the column settings.
3. Turn the Allow management of content types back on.
4. Go into each content type, set each column to require/optional/hidden there.

Comment: Hi, where can I find the setting for step 2? Is it under the column default value setting?

Comment: It is in list settings > columns section, then click the column name.

Answer (score 0):

These are required columns (the * asterisk indicates a required field).  You will not be able to save unless each required columns has a value, no blanks are allowed.  Or, if you have sufficient permissions, you can edit the columns in the settings to stop columns being required - when it is no longer required it means you can save it with a blank value.